# Can you use pandas to iterate over a dataframe while multiplying the previous row by a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As of now, I produced the below dataframe using python's pandas:

| ID | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50000 |
| 2 | 50000 |
| 3 | 50000 |
| 4 | 50000 |

My end goal would be to produce the table below. The logic would be to iterate over the dataframe and have it execute the below formula. For reference, I would like the first row (ID #1) to remain static.

**Formula:** (Prior Row * 10%) + Prior Row

| ID | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50000 |
| 2 | 55000 |
| 3 | 60500 |
| 4 | 66550 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a range of values based on the length of the DataFrame take the percentage to the power of this array then multiply by `Revenue`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Revenue': [50000, 50000, 50000, 50000]
})

percent = .1
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'] * ((1 + percent) ** np.arange(len(df)))
```

`df`:

```
   ID  Revenue
0   1  50000.0
1   2  55000.0
2   3  60500.0
3   4  66550.0
```

---

The operation:

```
(1 + percent) ** np.arange(len(df))
```

produces the current cumulative percentage at each row of the DataFrame:

```
[1.    1.1   1.21  1.331]
```

This is used to determine the current cumulative percentage by which to multiply Revenue.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": range(1,6), "Revenue":[50000]*5})
df["Revenue"] = df[["ID", "Revenue"]].apply(lambda x: x[1]*(1.1**(x[0]-1)),axis=1)
```

Comment: You might consider adding an explanation for how this code works.

Comment: @HenryEcker Originally wanted to add an explanation, but not after seeing your answer is accepted :) The same mathematical formula but via using `Series.apply()` function.